# Clear Required Field Validation Group

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, validation

I have 14 Fields in my Web page; and for all of them I use RequiredFieldValidator.
This Validator it works fine for all the fields. And when I have an error it caches it and display it to the proper error message area.
In this area I have a button in order to clear the messages and return to the input page.
After I'm caching an error or two I return to the first page by pressing the reset button... correcting the errors... and go forth.
 
When I'm passing variables to all the fields (which means everything is good) then normally the Validator has to be change and pass the trap (which I have in my code) with no error messages in it... 
Here is the trap code...

```
If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(RegisterValidationSummary.ValidationGroup) Then
                RegisterValidationSummary.Visible = True
                ErrorPanel.Visible = True
                btnClr.Visible = True
                Return
 End If
```

But no the trap works again and return me to the error area without any error displaying.
Only the reset button is there, and the error list is empty.
In order to be sure that all the errors are cleared I use in the reset button the following

```
Private Sub ClearValidators(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        RegisterValidationSummary.ValidationGroup = String.Empty

    End Sub
```

At this point the validators are cleared and the trap is not working... The problem is... that happens even when I have certain errors in my page or not.
Thus I use the following code in order to enable the Validators again.

```
For t = 0 To RegisterValidationSummary.Page.Validators.Count - 1
                RegisterValidationSummary.Page.Validators.Item(t).Validate()
Next
```

Validators are not enabled and of course the trap is not working.

Is someone how knows what is going on and how I may have a certain error erase from validators... and enabled again in order to validate again the fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing the validation wrong. First of all `ValidationGroup` is used to group validations so in a button click you validate the fields in that group. All server controls have this property so that you could group them together for validations by using the same text in this property. Checking the value in this property will not indicate that your values in your controls are valid or not.

So the following condition is always `True`

```
If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(RegisterValidationSummary.ValidationGroup) Then
```

Therefore, you'll see the reset button all the time.

And, by doing the following you are removing the `RegisterValidationSummary` control from the `ValidationGroup`.

```
RegisterValidationSummary.ValidationGroup = String.Empty
```

Therefore, after this point you'll not see any error messages since there's no ValidationSummary in the validation group to show the summary of error messages.

Hope I explained why you are seeying what you are seeing right now. Ok, since we know the issue we can easily fix it now.

You should do something like this. Basically we should make use of `Page.Validate()` and `If (Page.IsValid) Then` condition to check whether all fields in the `ValidationGroup` are valid.

```
Page.Validate()
If (Page.IsValid) Then
    ' If this condition is true that means all your fields have correct values
Else
    ' If this condition is true some of your fields are invalid. You can see that in the Validation summary message. 
    ' Not sure why you do the reset but your reset logic could go here
    RegisterValidationSummary.Visible = True
    ErrorPanel.Visible = True
    btnClr.Visible = True

End If
```

Hope this helps to resolve your issue.

Comment: Dear @Sam Your answer was grate, for two reasons A) Explained the work of validation with only two words. B) Gives me a solution; point it to the heart of the problem. I want to thank you very much.